# TeX Live 2015, moderncv and \footersymbol

Tags: texlive, moderncv

With TeX Live 2014 I could use the command

```
\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{{{\rmfamily\textcolor{color2}{~--~}}}}
```

to change the footer symbol in moderncv (`\moderncvstyle{casual}`). After the installation of TeX Live 2015 via the installer as described [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) and also with the `texlive-full` package in Ubuntu, I get the error message

```
./cv.tex:81: LaTeX Error: \footersymbol undefined.
l.81 \renewcommand*{\footersymbol}
make: *** [compositiv] Error 1
```

I use `\renewcommand*{\footersymbol …` to change the delimiter between the phone number and the mail address from the `•` to `–`.

[image]

The delimiter between street, city and country is the default behaviour.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the change from TeX Live 2014 to TeX Live 2015 you got a new version of document class `moderncv`.  The version I have is `moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class`.

Sometimes the author changed or better renamed some of the varaibles he uses in the class.

That happened also with your used variable `\footersymbol`.  Now it is defined as

```
\newcommand*{\footsymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}
```

Please see that you can omit the color that you used in your old command. The color is now set for the hole footer.  The `\rmfamily` can you omit depending of your used font.  If you get warnings in the footer, just add it again. See the file `moderncvfooti.sty`, lines 29-30 (read the comment!) and lines 76-97 (in line 82 the color is set).

So you can use now:

```
\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{%
  {{\rmfamily~--~}}%
}
```

or without `\rmfamily`:

```
\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{%
  {~--~}%
}
```

You can use this only if `moderncvfooti.sty` is called, for example with style `casual`.

Result with added last `\renewcommand` in example cv of `moderncv` with style `casual`:

[image: changed footer in casual style]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`moderncvfooti.sty`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvfooti.sty) you can see the following lines:

```
\newcommand*{\footsymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% [...stripped comment...]
```

So now you should not `\renewcommand{\footersymbol}` but `\renewcommand{\footsymbol}` instead.

Comment: Works, thank you, I now use `\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{{{\rmfamily\textcolor{color2}{~--~}}}}`

Comment: Sorry for the unaccepted answer. @Kurt answer is a little bit better. :\

Comment: @A.B. It is far better. Of course had to be accepted ;-)